# Pass empty string to column datatype is enum postgres got error

Tags: postgresql, enums, nestjs, typeorm

**I got an error when I pass an empty string to completed  but when I pass empty string to delivery_name is work fine**

```
 const queryBuilder = this.deliveryRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('delivery')
      .select([
        'delivery.delivery_id AS delivery_id',
        'delivery.price AS price',
        'delivery.delivery_date AS invoice_date',
        'delivery.invoice_id AS invoice_id',
        'delivery.completed AS completed',
        'delivery.deliveryman_id AS deliveryman_id',
        'deliveryman.delivery_name AS delivery_name',
        'deliveryman.vehicle AS vehicle',
        'deliveryman.phone AS phone',
      ]).orWhere('LOWER(deliveryman.delivery_name) LIKE LOWER(:delivery_name)', {
        delivery_name: `%${option.filter}%`,
      }).orWhere('delivery.completed = :completed', {
        completed: `%${option.filter}%`,
      })
```

**DeliveryEntity**

```
import { DeliveryManEntity, InvoiceEntity } from '@entity';
import { DeliveryStatus } from '../../../constant/delivery/delivery-status';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { ShareEntity } from '@share-entity';

@Entity({ name: 'delivery' })
export class DeliveryEntity extends ShareEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  delivery_id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true, default: 0 })
  price: number;

  @Column({ type: 'date', default: () => 'NOW()' })
  delivery_date: Date;

  @OneToOne(() => InvoiceEntity, (entity) => entity.delivery)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'invoice_id', referencedColumnName: 'invoice_id' })
  invoice: InvoiceEntity;
  @Column()
  invoice_id: number;

  @Column({
    enum: DeliveryStatus,
    type: 'enum',
    default: DeliveryStatus.PENDING,
    enumName: 'delivery_status',
    name: 'completed',
  })
  completed: DeliveryStatus;

  @ManyToOne(() => DeliveryManEntity, (entity) => entity.delivery)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'deliveryman_id',
    referencedColumnName: 'deliveryman_id',
  })
  deliveryman: DeliveryManEntity;
  @Column()
  deliveryman_id: number;
}
```

**Delivery Status**

```
export enum DeliveryStatus {
  PENDING = 'PENDING',
  COMPLETED = 'COMPLETED',
}
```

I want to pass an empty string to completed or I can pass PENDING OR COMPLETED

any solution how to query with empty string to completed field
I'm using typeorm + Nestjs +Postgresql

Comment: Why do you want to pass an empty string for an enum type? `DeliveryStatus` clearly accepts only `PENDING` and `COMPLETED` enum values.

Comment: i want go get both of these completed *PENDING* and *COMPLETED* in frontend and allow user to filter with *PENDING* or *COMPLETED* if empty string get both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, what you should be doing is something like below:

```js
const queryBuilder = this.deliveryRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('delivery')
      .select([
        'delivery.delivery_id AS delivery_id',
        'delivery.price AS price',
        'delivery.delivery_date AS invoice_date',
        'delivery.invoice_id AS invoice_id',
        'delivery.completed AS completed',
        'delivery.deliveryman_id AS deliveryman_id',
        'deliveryman.delivery_name AS delivery_name',
        'deliveryman.vehicle AS vehicle',
        'deliveryman.phone AS phone',
      ]).orWhere('LOWER(deliveryman.delivery_name) LIKE LOWER(:delivery_name)', {
        delivery_name: `%${option.filter}%`,
      });

const filter = `%${option.filter}%`;
if (filter === "") {
   queryBuilder.orWhere('delivery.completed IN (...:completed)', {
       completed: [DeliveryStatus.COMPLETED, DeliveryStatus.PENDING],
   });
} else {
   queryBuilder.orWhere('delivery.completed = :completed', {
       completed: filter,
   });
}
```

Comment: what is 3 dot? sir ...:completed?

Comment: `...` is called the spread operator in JavaScript which takes an array and expand its values. See this link for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: thank you for more information  really surprised  me  can use spread inside queryBuilder